# WebSocket in Node routes

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I have a REST API backend.  I'm trying to send WebSocket messages back to the client app when a site administrator invokes a route (i.e. updates user credentials);

```
let express = require("express"); 
let router = express.Router();

//update user credentials
router.put('/admin/user/:id', (req, res)=>{
// 1. Admin updates target user's profile/credentials
// 2. WebSocket message sent to target user client
// 3. Route sends res.status(200) to admin
});
```

I've seen a few WebSocket examples using 'ws', 'net', 'websocket' libraries, but they all show a simple event handling socket server that responds to socket messages outside of any express routes - let alone responds to a separate client.

Also, the event notification should be visible only to the target user and not all the other users connected to the socket server.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  The WebSocket server is independent of the route.

```
const WebSocket = require("ws"); 
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({port: 5555}); 


// handle socket communications
wss.on('connection', (session)=> { 
    session.send("HELLO SESSION: "+ session.userid); 

    session.on('message', (message)=> { 
    console.log(`MSG: "${message}" recived.`); 
    session.send("Got it."); 
    }); 

});

// close
wss.on('close', function close() {
  clearInterval(interval);
});

module.exports = wss;
```

Then, in the route, just include the service and use it to iterate through web socket connections like so:

```
let wss = require('./mysocketservice')
...
function sendAMessageTo(user, msg) {
  wss.clients.forEach(function each(s) {
  if(session.user = user)
  session.send("still there?.. "); 
}
```

}